# How to determine the date-and-time that a Linux process was started?

Tags: linux, process, statistics

If I look at /proc/6945/stat then I get a series of numbers, one of which is the number of CPU-centiseconds for which the process has been running.

But I'm running these processes on heavily-loaded boxes, and what I'm interested in is the clock-time when the job will finish, for which I want to know the clock-time that it started.

The timestamps on files in /proc/6945 look to be in the right sort of range but I can't find a particular file which consistently has the right clock-time on it.

As always I can't modify the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a project on github that does this in perl. You can find it here:

https://github.com/cormander/psj

The code you're wanting is in `lib/Proc/PID.pm`, and here is the snippit (with comments removed):

```
use POSIX qw(ceil sysconf _SC_CLK_TCK);

sub _start_time {
    my $pid = shift->pid;

    my $tickspersec = sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);

    my ($secs_since_boot) = split /\./, file_read("/proc/uptime");
    $secs_since_boot *= $tickspersec;

    my $start_time = (split / /, file_read("/proc/$pid/stat"))[21];

    return ceil(time() - (($secs_since_boot - $start_time) / $tickspersec));
}
```

Beware the non-standard code function `file_read` in here, but that should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

Timestamps of the directories in /proc are useless.

I was advised to look at 'man proc'; this says that /proc/$PID/stat field 21 records the start-time of the process **in kernel jiffies since boot** ... so:

```
open A,"< /proc/stat"; while (<A>) { if (/^btime ([0-9]*)/) { $btime = $1 } }
```

to obtain the boot time, then

```
my @statl = split " ",`cat /proc/$i/stat`;
$starttime_jiffies = $statl[21];
$starttime_ut = $btime + $starttime_jiffies / $jiffies_per_second;
$cputime = time-$starttime_ut
```

but I set $jiffies_per_second to 100 because I don't know how to ask the kernel for its value from perl.

Comment: Looking at do_task_stat() and nsec_to_clock_t() the count is measured in USER_HZ, which can be retrieved using POSIX::sysconf(&POSIX::_SC_CLK_TCK).

Answer (score 0):

Use the creation timestamp of the /proc/6945 directory (or whatever PID), rather than looking at the files it contains.  For example:

```
ls -ld /proc/6945
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me: I have cases where /proc/$PID seems to be created after the process started, eg /proc/$PID is created 46 minutes ago but the single-threaded process has accumulated 91 minutes CPU time

Comment: Well I don't know about that CPU time paradox you mention, but if you actually start a few programs on your system I think you will find that what I posted gives you what you asked for.  If you can find a counter-example I'd love to know about it.

Comment: I don't know how to replicate in a controlled environment, but I have half a dozen processes here (out of about 100 running in parallel) with the paradoxical property; one of the routines that starts some of the processes leaves a dropping with a timestamp (but not all of them, otherwise I wouldn't ask the root question), so it's easy to tell.

Comment: As far as I can see, atime/mtime/ctime on the files in /proc are always the time the inode is created, not the process.  See various files in fs/proc.

Comment: @TomWomack I could imagine that the mtime on /proc/<pid> might change if a file was added to the directory later.  What about mtime on /proc/<pid>/cmdline?  That should only change if the process becomes a zombie.  Re the last comment, surely for some purposes the inode times would be close enough?

Comment: Ah, now I get what Richard meant - do an "ls" of /proc and the pid directories which have been added since the last time the directory was read are marked with the current time.  Presumably they are created lazily.

Answer (score 0):

Bash command to get the start date of some process:

```
date -d @$(cat /proc/PID/stat | awk "{printf \"%.0f\", $(grep btime /proc/stat | cut -d ' ' -f 2)+\$22/$(getconf CLK_TCK);}")
```