# Is there a sure way to uniquely identify a process?

Tags: unix

I'm sending emails from a database using a server side script. I want to check if the process I created for the each email list is still running, so I can restart the script for that particular list if it's not. I thought about using PID but I'm wondering if there's a more reliable way to identify them without worrying about PID recycling and having a different process with the same PID.

Comment: Use composite ID made of PID + process [startup timestamp][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641642/how-to-determine-the-date-and-time-that-a-linux-process-was-started

Answer (score 0):

If your server side script is named "db_email.sh" your monitor script could just look for those processes and count the results.

```
PROCESS_COUNT=$(ps -eaf | grep "[d]b_email.sh" | wc -l)
if [[ $PROCESS_COUNT -eq 0 ]]; then
   echo "He's dead, Jim"
fi
```

The grep command uses a regular expression, square bracket around one of the letters, so that it won't find itself in the process listing and inflate your count by 1.